# in R, create an algorithm to correct typing errors

Tags: r

I would like to create an algorithm able to correct some typing errors. In my case, I have a dataframe with the following variables, for example:

```
data
 id_number   name
 ***123***   Maria dos Santos Magalhães
 ***123**    Maria Santos Magalhães
 ***329**    Lucas Barbosa 
 ***329**    Danilo Carvalho
 ***732**    Paulo Silva da Fonseca
 ***732**    Wagner Silva Junior
 ***732**    Paulo Silva Fonseca
```

Explainig the firts variable: id_number is the identification of each citizen, but it is not showed enterely. The source only provides the middle numbers.

I would like to construct a probabilist algorithm able to indicate or say if two citizens with the same middle id_number are the same or differents citizens.

For example, in the 732 group, Maria dos Santos Magalhães and Maria Santos Magalhães are, with high probability, the same citizens. In the group ***329**, the two citizens are, with high propabilty, diferents.

The third group is more interesting, Paulo Silva da Fonseca and Wagner Silva Junior aren't the same citizens, but Paulo Silva da Fonseca and Paulo Silva Fonseca are, with high probability, the same citizens

Some ideias?

Comment: Though not directly related, [fuzzyjoin](https://github.com/dgrtwo/fuzzyjoin) does some fuzzy matching of words. I have not used it yet but plan on playing with it soon.

Comment: With some adaptation, it may be useful

Comment: Perhaps more appropriate would be doing it directly with [`stringdist`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringdist/index.html). That is, group by `id_number`-middle-digits, compare all names, and those that fall under a threshold (yours to determine experimentally) are assumed similar enough.

Comment: or even `adist` in base R

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution using `adist` and `dplyr` package. I slightly changed your data.frame for the sake of the example by adding a `de Fonseca`.

First, we recreate your data:

```
data <- read.table(text="
id_number;name
123;Maria dos Santos Magalhães
123;Maria Santos Magalhães
329;Lucas Barbosa 
329;Danilo Carvalho
732;Paulo Silva de Fonseca
732;Paulo Silva da Fonseca
732;Wagner Silva Junior
732;Paulo Silva Fonseca", h=T, sep=";")
```

Here is the function that will be called on each `id_number` group. It calculate the distance matrix using `adist` and [Levenshtein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) distance. Then, if duplicates are found, below a certain `thres`,  we return all (but the first) similar names. They will be removed, note the `-`.  If no duplicates are found, we return all indices in the group, so that nothing is removed.

```
library(dplyr)

possible_duplicates <- function(ch, thresh=5) {
  # calculate Levenshtein distance
  d <- ch %>% adist()

  # finds possible duplicates
  # (0 is for perfect match, we dont want them)
  # (above thres is fine, you will need to adjust this)
  dup <- which(d != 0 & d < thresh, arr.ind=TRUE)  %>%  
         as.numeric()  %>% unique()  %>% sort() 

  # case where duplicates where found, all but the first are removed
  if (length(dup)>1)
    -dup[-1]
  # no duplicate we won't slice then
  else
    seq_along(ch)
}
```

Here is a pipe using it: we first `group_by` `id_number`, we apply on each group our `possible_duplicate` function which result is used for `slice`-ing.

```
data %>% 
  group_by(id_number) %>% 
  slice(possible_duplicates(name)) %>% 
  ungroup()

Source: local data frame [5 x 2]

id_number                       name
(int)                     (fctr)
1       123 Maria dos Santos Magalhães
2       329             Lucas Barbosa 
3       329            Danilo Carvalho
4       732     Paulo Silva de Fonseca
5       732        Wagner Silva Junior
```

If you want a more restrictive threshold (5 by default), you can:

```
data %>% 
  group_by(id_number) %>% 
  slice(possible_duplicates(name, 2)) %>% 
  ungroup()

Source: local data frame [7 x 2]

id_number                       name
(int)                     (fctr)
1       123 Maria dos Santos Magalhães
2       123     Maria Santos Magalhães
3       329             Lucas Barbosa 
4       329            Danilo Carvalho
5       732     Paulo Silva de Fonseca
6       732        Wagner Silva Junior
7       732        Paulo Silva Fonseca
```

Is this what you wanted?

Comment: No. I can't understand this case: if  ch <- c("JOS ANTONIO PEREIRA" , "JOSE ANTONIO PEREIRA", "WALLACE MAGALH ES MARTINS" , "WALLACE MAGALHAES MARTINS"), possible_duplicates(ch) isn't good.